# Average number of draws to repeat a random number?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

In a random sequence of equiprobable integer numbers between [1,n], how can I find the average number of draws needed for a single integer to repeat? Please recomment a good book.

Comment: This is the ["average" variant of the birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people) - note that you must add $1$ to Wikipedia's $Q(M)$